# Defining Python decorators for a complete module

Tags: python, decorator

I have a module which contains a lot of functions (more than 25). I want to add a common decorator function to each of these functions. The normal way to do is to add a @decorator line above each function, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it? Probably I can declare a global decorator at the top of the module or something else?

Note that since I am using someone else's code, I want to minimize the number of lines changed, so modifying the module is not ideal for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If your decorator is called `my_decorator`

```
### Decorate all the above functions
import types
for k,v in globals().items():
    if isinstance(v, types.FunctionType):
        globals()[k] = my_decorator(v)
```

You could also apply this to the module after importing it

```
import othermodule
import types
for k,v in vars(othermodule).items():
    if isinstance(v, types.FunctionType):
        vars(othermodule)[k] = my_decorator(v)
```

Comment: This is perfectly safe - and I actually use things like this in a real project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This does work for me, but there is a small problem that it also adds the functions which I have imported (like "from copy import deepcopy") ... is there a way I can skip these functions and only add the functions that I myself defined at the top level in the module? ... thanks!

Comment: replace "vars(othermodule)[k] = my_decorator(v)" with "setattr(othermodule, k, my_decorator(v))" in order to avoid possible "'dictproxy' object does not support item assignment"

Comment: Beware, though, that this makes it harder for a reader to realize that the functions are decorated. I agree sometimes it's  a fine approach, but it goes a little against the "explicit is better than implicit" guideline.

Answer (score 10):

I think applying a decorator en-masse such that it's not obvious where you will go looking to find out about the function (at its definition) is generally a bad idea. Explicit is better than implicit, and all that.

If you want to apply the decorator to some third party module's functions, without modifying the third-party code, here is how I would do it:

```
# my_wrapper_module.py

import some_module
import functools

def some_decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        ...
    return wrapper

FUNCTION_NAMES = [
    'some_func_1',
    'some_func_2',
    'some_func_3',
    ...
]

for name in FUNCTION_NAMES:
    globals()[name] = some_decorator(getattr(some_module, name))
```

And then use these functions elsewhere by doing `from my_wrapper_module import some_func_2`, etc.

For me, this has the following advantages:

1. No need to modify the third-party source file
2. It is clear from the call site that I should go look at `my_wrapper_module` to see what I'm calling, and that I'm not using the undecorated versions of the functions
3. It is clear from `my_wrapper_module` what functions are being exported, that they originally come from `some_module`, and that they all have the same decorator applied
4. Any code that imports `some_module` directly isn't silently and inexplicably affected; this could be particularly important if the third-party code is more than one module

But if what you're trying to do is hack a third-party library so that internal calls *are* affected, then this is not what you want.

Comment: Like your idea of ​​creating `wrapper_module`. By the way, I've deleted my answer (because @gnibbler's is more complete and has correct cheking for function type).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I did the following

Comment: @reclosedev Cheers, I've removed the reference to your answer now.