# How to write unit tests to ensure my code follows HTTP redirects?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-requests, http-redirect

I am using the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module to make HTTP calls internally within my module.

I understand that this:

```
r = requests.post('http://github.com', allow_redirects=True)
```

will follow HTTP redirects.

Of course, I make multiple calls to `requests` from my own modules API and I want to write a unit test that ensures that requests is always following redirects. How should I go about this?

On first blush, my thought is to fire off a simple HTTP server in my tests to mimic the HTTP calls. I'm not sure how I can mock out the whole `requests` method calls which rely on network communications.

Comment: Unless the verb is HEAD, Requests will always follow redirection. Tests for requests here: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/test_requests.py

Answer (score 1):

If it's a *requirement* that your code always follow redirects, then I would encode this explicitly in an interface function. Then insist that all calls to `requests.post` are made via your function instead. In its simplest form, this is just a wrapper method:

```
def my_post(*args, **kwargs):
    return requests.post(*args, allow_redirects=True, **kwargs)
```

If you wanted to preserve the existing API, and just override its behaviour, you could monkeypatch and [decorate the third-party function at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951787/defining-python-decorators-for-a-complete-module).

You should avoid testing that the library itself performs the redirects. That should be tested elsewhere, and presumably you trust the library. All you need to test is that you call the library function correctly. This is a general principle.

That keeps your test simple: just mock the call to `requests.post`, and confirm the arguments you intend, including `allow_redirects=True`, are passed.