# Applying decorator to all functions in a python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, memoization, python-decorators

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8951787/2593236), but in my case the accepted answer does not decorate all the functions in the package when they are used within the the package and I'm not sure why.

For example, I have a project set up like this:

```
project/
    package/ 
        __init__.py
        module_a.py
        module_b.py
    main.py
```

`__init__.py`

```
from .module_a import *
from .module_b import *

import types
# This is the decorator that will be used
from functools import lru_cache

for name, obj in list(globals().items()):
    if isinstance(obj, types.FunctionType):
        globals()[name] = lru_cache(maxsize=100)(obj)
```

`module_a.py`

```
from .module_b import b

def a(arg):
    return b
```

`module_b.py`

```
def b(arg):
    return arg
```

`main.py`

```
import package

print(package.a.cache_info())
print(package.a(None).cache_info())
print(package.b.cache_info())
```

When the package is imported, `__init__.py` decorates the functions in `globals` just fine when stepping through the code. However, if I execute `main.py` I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\pbreach\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/pbreach/PycharmProjects/project/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=0, maxsize=100, currsize=0)
  File "C:/Users/pbreach/PycharmProjects/project/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(package.a(None).cache_info())
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'cache_info'
```

Which would mean that `b` is not decorated when imported from `module_b` in `module_a`.

Why does this only happen in the second line? What might be a way to accomplish this?

I am fine with doing the decorating either during import in `__init__.py` or in `main.py`, but would rather not have to apply the decorator inside each module in `package` as in my case there are quite a few of them.

## EDIT:

I think the issue is because `globals` in `__init__.py` is a different namespace than when `b` is imported into `module_a` meaning there are two different instances of the same function. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing `b` from `module_b` in `module_a` before you get a chance to decorate it with `functools.lru_cache`.

The only viable alternative I see, is first explicitly decorating functions that get imported and used in other submodules and then applying the decorator to all other functions.

Using your example, first decorate `b` from `module_b` and then decorate the rest:

```
from package import module_b

import types
# This is the decorator that will be used
from functools import lru_cache
module_b.b = lru_cache(maxsize=100)(module_b.b)

from .module_a import *
from .module_b import *

for name, obj in list(globals().items()):
    if isinstance(obj, types.FunctionType):
        globals()[name] = lru_cache(maxsize=100)(obj)
```

Another option, as I stated in a comment, would be to use an `if` clause inside the modules that contain functions that get included in other modules were the wrapping would occur there.

So in `module_b.py` you could perform something like this:

```
if __name__ != '__main__':
    from functools import lru_cache
    b = lru_cache(b)
```

this only catches the case where the module isn't run as `__main__`. Now when another module includes this module and it's body gets executed, the wrapping will be performed here instead of `__init__.py`.

Comment: I see this makes sense now... the only issue is that in my use case there are 12 modules with over 400 different functions and imports between them but only of the form `from . import module_x`

Comment: Would it be possible to iterate through all the functions in each module in `__init.py__` and apply the decorator before the * imports?

Comment: If you could order them in a way which assures that a function from `module_X` has already been wrapped before being imported in `module_Y` and used, yes. Another option could only be using an `if __name__ != __main__:` in each sub-module that gets imported in another sub-module and decorating inside that clause.

Comment: Ok I think this might work will give it a try on work PC

Comment: The first option was not possible (if the imports were * there would be a circular import), but the second one works! This was a good learning experience. Thanks!