# Adding time delay to selenium

Tags: python, selenium, oop

I want to wrap webdriver to cause it to wait after every operation. I have the following function, which I thought might work (I'm testing with the print function):

```
def sleep_driver(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("sleeping")
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

However when I run:

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
webdriver = sleep_driver(wd)

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
```

I get:

```
  File "myfile.py", line 204, in <module>
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'ChromeOptions'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*`webdriver` is a module* and there are some caveats if you want to "decorate" a module  in Python:

- [Defining Python decorators for a complete module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8951787/771848)

I would instead subclass a driver and override the [`execute()` method](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute), which is *actually responsible for sending webdriver commands*:

```
class MyChromeDriver(webdriver.Chrome):
    def execute(self, driver_command, params=None):
        # add a delay here      

        return super(MyChromeDriver, self).execute(driver_command, params=params)
```